# How can I convert a UNICODE word to an International Domain Name? (and back)

Tags: domain-name-system, scripting, idn

I want to convert a few Unicode words to an International Domain Name, (and back) but can't find a script or other resource to do it on a Windows PC.

Does anyone have such a tool?

Answer (score 6):

instead of punycode  as @ignacio-vazquez-abrams said, much better using 'idna' which will give you a better translation (it includes 'xn--' code)
that would be:

```
>>>> u'español'.encode('idna')
'xn--espaol-zwa'
```

P.S.: wanted to comment on his response, but I couldn't :S

Answer (score 2):

[Python](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads) does it natively.

```
>>> u'あら？'.encode('punycode')
'l8jxh6512d'
>>> print 'p8j2bk2072s'.decode('punycode')
そうだ！
```

Comment: Very cool example!! and i love python!! +1

Comment: PS: You need to add xn- in front of what python outputs you. GNU has a Punycode library for C/C++ and C# also.